# How to pass user roles to Jersey Rest services

Tags: grails, spring-boot, jersey

I need to implement security while trying to access Jersey Rest services in Spring boot environment, I am accessing these services from Grails and Grails application has different roles for users .
How should I pass security roles in every request I make to Rest api? I am implementing security first time, any guidance will be helpful.
If I receive roles at Rest end then I can use SecurityContext from Jersey or WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter from Spring security to check if user has proper roles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used json to pass encrypted credentials details like this:
    def authString = (login + ":" + p password).getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${authString}")`

Thanks